# Performing sqlcmd for query containing FOR XML and writing output in XML path. Generated XML format is damaged and some text are removed

Tags: sql-server, xml, sqlcmd

I have SQL query for XML like the following (SQL Server 2012):

```
Use MedStreaming
SELECT distinct 1 as Tag,
   NULL as Parent,  
   NULL AS [ExamTypes!1],
   NULL as [ExamType!2!ExamTypeID],  
   NULL       as [Template!3!ShortString],  
   NULL       as [Template!3!Order]
UNION ALL 
SELECT distinct 2    as Tag,  
   1 as Parent,  
   NULL,
   Temp_Type.ExamTypeId as [ExamType!2!ExamTypeID],  
   NULL       as [Template!3!ShortString],  
   NULL       as [Template!3!Order]  
FROM   LayoutSectionTemplate_ExamType AS Temp_Type  
INNER JOIN LayoutSection_Template as temp
ON Temp_Type.TemplateId = temp.TemplateId
UNION ALL  
SELECT 3 as Tag,  
   2 as Parent, 
   NULL, 
   Temp_Type.ExamTypeId,  
   temp.ShortString,
   Temp_Type.[Order]
FROM   LayoutSectionTemplate_ExamType AS Temp_Type  
INNER JOIN LayoutSection_Template as temp 
ON  Temp_Type.TemplateId = temp.TemplateId 
ORDER BY [ExamType!2!ExamTypeID],[Template!3!Order]  
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

I try to call it and write the XML result in an XML file using the following command:

```
sqlcmd -i "%~dp0\MedStreaming.Util\Scripts\GetExamTypes-TemplatesRelations.sql" -o "C:\temp\examTypes-reportsTemplates.xml"
```

But the file result XML format is not correct, and some texts are removed.
I tried to put "XML ON" on the first of the query, but it doesn't work (it gives me syntax error).

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

This is an [annoying limitation of `SQLCMD` interface](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/786004/sqlcmd-with-xml-on-break-lines-on-large-output) (*same for `Invoke-SqlCmd` the Powershell module*) - you have to put the **XML** or **JSON** output into `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or `XML` datatype so that `SQLCMD` can handle the output properly. There is a **2MB rowsize threshold** for `SQLCMD` output whereafter it starts chunking the output data into additional `DataRows`.

***Note:*** You should also set `MaxCharLength` [if the data exceeds 4K characters in size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28375111/175679).

#### SQLCMD XML Output

```sql
DECLARE @XML as XML
SET @XML= (select Name from TestXML For XML path ('')
```

#### SQLCMD JSON Output

```sql
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @json = (select * from mytable for json auto)
select * from openjson(@json)
```

Another option is to [use `bcp` utility which outputs directly to disk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx) for larger data dumps.